# Make Microsoft Word change number literals to spellings?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, autocorrect

In English, [it's better style to spell numbers out](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/979/why-do-english-writers-avoid-explicit-numerals).

How can I make Word flag this as a grammar error or auto-correct it? (specifically 2007)

Answer (score 2):

Add entries into the Auto Correct to replace "1" with "one", etc.

To set these options, click on the Windows Office icon in the top left corner, and click "Word Options" on the bottom of the window.

[image: Word Options Button]

Then, click the "Proofing" tab, and select the "AutoCorrect Options" button.

[image: AutoCorrect Options]

Last, make sure the "Replace text as you type" (Green arrow) is checked. Put what you want to replace in the box that says "Replace" (Blue arrow) and what you wish to replace with in the "With" box (Orange arrow). Click the "Add" button (Dark Blue arrow).

[image: Adding words to AutoCorrect]

Put in an entry for every numerical value you wish to replace and the corresponding word, and give it a test!

Comment: This option doesn't scale though.  If you want to flag <10 it's not a problem.  <100 becomes an exercise in tedium to implement.  <1000 (or higher) is practically impossible due to the amount of time it would suck up.

Comment: Correct, difficult to scale up. However, I never said it would be a fast solution! :) @CrazyJugglerDrummer: If you've got the guts to give it a go, check out this article from Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/135778 You could manually add a butt-load of entries to the file itself, though...

Comment: writing a script to populate hundreds or thousands of entries into the file would be a reasonable option I suppose; assuming that the file getting huge doesn't end up causing performance issues anyway.  That said your KB article is only for office 95/97.  Searching on my computer I found 4 .acl files in he office12 tree but opening them in a text editor I don't think they're plain text.